# Edittext focus is not changing in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-event

In my layout I am using two `Spinner` and `Editext` ,when I click outside the `Edittext` soft keypad is not hiding and also `Edittext` focus is not changing..
My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bgfind"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drivernametext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/drivernametext"
        android:textColor="@color/splashscreen"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/driverSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ui_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdownbtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carRegNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/carRegNumber"
        android:textColor="@color/splashscreen"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/carRegNumberedit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ui_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:hint="@string/carRegNumber"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/brandcolor"
        android:textColorHint="@color/edit_hint"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inglottext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/inglottext"
        android:textColor="@color/splashscreen"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/inglotspinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdownbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ui_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ui_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:text="@string/Done"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in programatically i have tried

```
final EditText carRegEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.carRegNumberedit);
        carRegEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (!hasFocus) {
                    carRegEdit.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(carRegEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

            }
        });
```

in `Activity` declaration I also tried, still soft keypad is not hiding.
How to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

you suppose Handle Click Event of your root layout to hide keyboad if open.
when any other  place will be clicked your keyboard will hide.